# converting byte() variable to string with encoding

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, character-encoding

I am consuming messages and the messages are stored in byte() format and I tried to convert it with proper encoding to a string but still see the unicode characters when writing it to a file. What am I doing wrong here

```
 xwriter = New XmlTextWriter(filename,Encoding.UTF8)
 Dim body As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(result.Body)
'body = replaceIllegalXMLChars(body)  ///tried converting them explicitly but did not work
 xwriter.WriteString(post)
 xwriter.Flush()
```

Sample output:

```
   &lt;avataruri&gt;http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1651487744/Vman_normal.jpg
   &lt;/avataruri&gt;
   &lt;suitable&gt;0&lt;/suitable&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `XmlTextWriter`.

`XmlTextWriter` helps you generate your own XML by escaping text and writing tag names.
Calling `WriteString()` will write the text you pass as XML *content*, correctly escaping special characters.

If you have a string of existing XML, and you want to write it to a file, you should write it just like any other string, using the `File` class.

You don't even need to decode the bytes; you can write them directly to disk.

Comment: oh yes...I just copied this from old code to create xml documents but I guess I could just use a streamwriter or stringbuilder and write to a text file if I am understanding you correctly right?

Comment: I want to create an xml document and the message is already formatted in xml format.